# Update the status and progress back to react native before resolving promise from a native module call

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am calling a native module function from react-native to register user's bio-metric

(PS: I am not using android's built-in bio-metric scanner. Using a third party module connected via USB.)

This is a very long operation and the code has to communicate to user via messages which are displayed in react-native UI. Along with this I need to show the progress of the capture process. Since we would be able to **resolve the promise object passed to the native module only once**, Is there any other way I could communicate back to the react-native realm from the native module until the whole process is complete and then I resolve the promise?